# Will taking MassGainer and Creatine risk damage to my body in long run?

Tags: muscle-mass, health-risk, creatine

I've been taking MassGainer for the last week and I am going to buy some [Creatine](http://www.healthkart.com/sv/muscleblaze-micronized-creatine/SP-8688?navKey=VRNT-50601) soon.

This is my 5th year at the gym (I'm 28, 5'10", 68kg). I go thrice a week. I will never stop exercising (it's the way life is meant to be). I have a very tight, lean body with perfect cuts and shape.

This year, I have decided to gain mass.

My question is whether, if I take MassGainer and Creatine and then stop taking it once its finished, my body will still crave for it, or if I will lose my mass if I stop taking it.

Comment: MassGainers are just carbs, you eat carbs every day. With creatine your mostly lose the water retained, meaning yes you will lose a bit mass, but nothing too important. You don't have to cycle creatine in my opinion. Might be wrong there.

Comment: I have already placed the order. But my question still remains, will my body crave for these afterwards if I stop these supplements !

Comment: You eat carbs every day, do yo crave them? Depends. I have been on and off from creatine and no, i did not crave for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of these supplements are habit forming so no, your body will not "crave" them after you stop using them. However, the effects of both will subside when you stop taking them.

If you need to supplement a weight gainer to pack on mass, you will likely need to continue to keep your caloric intake at a certain level to continue to sustain your bulk.

With Creatine it's a little different. Effectively it allows you to push harder sets and the muscle gains made as a result are proportionally greater to the gains you'd make without supplementing. If you maintain at or just below the levels achieved during supplementation after you quit using creatine, most of those gains will remain.

Comment: Thanks, so i just need to stay in the same performance after stopped taking Creatine to maintain the mass.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanna add something (i might be wrong, a doctor confirmation would be appreciated) but 98% of mass gainers use high in sugar and high IG carbs as a calorie source. Aka maltodextrine or fructose etc. A high dose of sugar (not carbs, >sugar<) in the very long term can give you diabetes. So if you're like me and need a shitload of calories to pack on mass and use gainer everyday , prefer gainers that don't have maltodextrine but use things like oats instead (low IG and low sugar). Plus they taste better in general. I can't give you a link to good gainers I guess but search a website with bulk in the name you might be interested :)

Answer (score 1):

If using something like mass gainer (mostly dexstrose) is the only way you're able to maintain a high calorie intake, then you will lose mass if you stop taking it. I don't think this is the case though, just eat more food generally and you will maintain your muscle weight.

Creatine gives you a performance boost that can make you gain more muscle since you work harder in the gym, when you stop taking it, you will perform worse and that will decrease the signal that increase muscle mass.